# PhpMyAdmin not access able after setting tomcat on port 80

Tags: java, tomcat, redirect, phpmyadmin

I just set tomcat on port 80
by adding this on /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin tomcat@something.com
    ServerName something.com
    ServerAlias www.something.com


    ProxyRequests Off 
    ProxyPreserveHost On 
    <Proxy *> 
       Order allow,deny 
       Allow from all 
    </Proxy> 
 ProxyPass / http://something.com:8080/ 
 ProxyPassReverse / http://something.com:8080/ 

 ErrorLog logs/something.com-error_log 
 CustomLog logs/something.com-access_log common 

</VirtualHost>
```

But now i am trying to access something.com/phpMyadmin

It is redirecting to something.com:8080/something.com

which is a wrong path

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line right **before** your existing `ProxyPass`:

```
ProxyPass /phpMyadmin !
```

It tells Apache **not** to proxy this path to Tomcat. Everything else will be proxied.